# Edits on PHP.INI not making effect

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm on MacOS Mojave. phpinfo() shows my php.ini file is on

/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

But the problem is, i edit it, put new modules to be loaded, even put invalid instructions, and Apache log file show nothing / no errors when i restart it.

Is there any other location php.ini can be, even if phpinfo() shows the location above ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting the whole system? I've seen some weird issues where files weren't saving even though they appeared to, when I restarted my entire server I lost all the changes I made to my php.ini file and had to redo it, it worked after that

Comment: After you make changes to your php.ini file you will need to restart the web server.

Comment: or if you're running FPM or a similiarly separate FastCGI Process Manager you'll need to restart _that_ to apply changes to PHP config.

Comment: @unixmiah I'm restarting Apache.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm running Apache / PHP on MacOS Mojave... how can i know if i'm in the situation you said ?

Comment: Well i found out that the changes i made on php.ini are being respected, but the log just won't show on Apache error file... To see it i need to run php itself. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Apache not using PHP from /usr/local/php5/ path? Did you install another PHP version (or update) before? 
Can you please check phpinfo? For example what it does say for "Loaded Configuration File" and "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"